# Finding a Trigonometric Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the expressions **$V_k$** and **$\psi_k$** of this equation:

[image]

The source: On the nonlinear electromagnetic coupling between a coil and an oscillating magnet

link: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/43/29/295005/meta

[image]

N, $\psi$ and $\lambda$ are all constants
r,x and z are just geometrical parameters.

Comment: What is $\;\Theta\;$ ? The image isn't complete...

Comment: @DonAntonio Basically it is only a function of y. I added it for clarification.

Comment: I ask because $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(a\sin\omega t\right)^k}{k!}=e^{a\sin\omega t}\;$$ but with that weird differential inside the sum it most surely is something very different. It also isn't clear, mathematically, what are $\;V_k\;,\;\;\psi\;$ and where they come from...